# Getting Error Running Query with Concatenation

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to run a query to join two columns together, count number of trips, and roundup the average of trip duration. I'm getting error

```
SELECT 
    usertype,
    CONCAT(start_station_name, "to", end_station_name) AS Route,
    COUNT(*) AS Num_Trips,
    ROUND(AVG(CAST(tripduration AS INT64)/60), 2) AS Duration 
FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` 
GROUP BY
    start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype
ORDER BY
    Num_Trips DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: It says "cannot access field 2 on a value with type FLOAT64"

Comment: see fix i just did inside your question. `ROUND(AVG(CAST(tripduration AS INT64)/60). 2)` should be `ROUND(AVG(CAST(tripduration AS INT64)/60), 2)`