# I am having issues with a SQL query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I was following along with my instructor on the google data analytics course, below is the code I wrote and I keep getting an error

```
SELECT  
  usertype,
  CONCAT(start_station_name, " to ", end_station_name) AS route,
  COUNT(*) as num_trips,
  ROUND(AVG(cast(tripduration as int64)/60).2)
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` 
GROUP BY
  start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype
ORDER BY
  num_trips DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The error is
Cannot access field 2 on a value with type FLOAT64 at [5:45]

Comment: Without knowing your data, it's difficult to say if this is the only problem, but you are using the function ROUND incorrectly. The function expects two parameters that need to be separated by comma, not by dot, so it must be  ...),2) instead of ...).2) in the line before your from clause begins.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/72417695/5221944

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your round function, it is written as `ROUND(AVG(cast(tripduration as int64)/60).2)` and it is supposed to be `ROUND(AVG(cast(tripduration as int64)/60), 2)`.

The dot represents that you are trying to access the field "2" of the  `AVG(cast(tripduration as int64)/60)` value, which is a FLOAT64, therefore creating the error *"Cannot access field 2 on a value with type FLOAT64 at [5:45]".*